# Getting inserted subtree after CKEDITOR's Editor#insertHtml

Tags: ckeditor, inserthtml

In order for the new widgets feature to be correctly initialised on newly injected content, it's necessary to use `insertHtml` as widgets processing/injection is applied during html processing. Inserting ready-made elements via `insertElement` or `insertElementIntoRange` will not trigger the check for new widgets.

The issue occurs when there's a desire for adding non-serializable metadata to the injected content e.g. event handlers. This has to be done after content injection since it won't live through, but I can't see a way to get `insertHtml` (or a related method) to return a reference to the injected DOM node(s).

Is there a way, or is it necessary to add serializable hooks (e.g. an id) and use that for a second pass after injection?